# Get a component from JList by click location

Tags: java, swing, location, selection, jlist

How can I fetch a component from a `JList`, with the click location?

I have my own list cell renderer where I insert some panels and labels.
Now i want to get e.g. the label where the user clicked at.

I tried the method `list.getComponentAt(evt.getPoint());` but it returns only the entire `JList`.

Comment: For a `JList`, add a [`ListSelectionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/ListSelectionListener.html).  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: The `JList` does not container any components.  It uses the `ListCellRenderer` to paint a "rubber stamp" of the component onto the list.  That is, each element in the list is rendered using the same/single `ListCellRenderer`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I've not tested this, but the basics would be...

1. Use `JList#locationToIndex(Point)` to get the index of the element at
   the given point.
2. Get the "element" at the specified index (using
   `JList#getModel#getElementAt(int)`).
3. Get the `ListCellRenderer` using `JList#getCellRenderer`.
4. Render the element and get it's `Component` representation
5. Set the renderer's bounds to the required cell bounds
6. Convert the original `Point` to the `Component`s context
7. Use `getComponentAt` on the renderer...

Possibly, something like...

```
int index = list.locationToIndex(p);
Object value = list.getModel().getElementAt(int);
Component comp = listCellRenderer.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, true, true);
comp.setBounds(list.getCellBounds(index, index));
Point contextPoint = SwingUtilities.convertPoint(list, p, comp);
Component child = comp.getComponentAt(contextPoint);
```

Answer (score 2):

MadProgrammer's works fine as long as the user doesn't click outside a cell. If he does that, the index returned by locationToIndex() will be the last index's cell, so the converted point will be "under" the rendered component

To check if the user really clicked a cell you have to do:

```
int index = list.locationToIndex(p);
if (index > -1 && list.getCellBounds(index, index).contains(p)){
    // rest of MadProgrammer solution
    ...
}
```

Comment: This solved the problem I had where whenever I clicked below the list items, it would always get the last component.